# Is there a `let` quantifier in LATEX?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Is there a `let` quantifier in LATEX? (It looks like `\exists`, but without a middle stick)

Comment: `\usepackage{ amssymb }\sqsupset`. Have a look at [“How to look up a symbol?”](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: I tried this symbol, but it's lower and longer than `\exists`

Comment: I never heard of that mathematical notation, could you show an example so that we can see ?

Comment: I have not seen that notation and there is no Unicode character with "let" (with a mathematical meaning) in its name.  Can you link to a pdf where this is used so we can see what font character it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a (humble) possibility using `tikz`. It won't resist scaling though

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amstext}
\newlength{\tempheight}
\newcommand{\Let}[0]{%
\mathbin{\text{\settoheight{\tempheight}{\mathstrut}\raisebox{0.5\pgflinewidth}{%
\tikz[baseline,line cap=round,line join=round] \draw (0,0) --++ (0.4em,0) --++ (0,1.5ex) --++ (-0.4em,0);%
}}}}
\begin{document}
$\Let\exists\alpha\beta\gamma$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used that quantor during my stury in Saint-Petersburg State University, and I wonder, if that sign being used in other places. Searched for it several times, found an old FIDO mail with DIY-version:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\def\letus{%
    \mathord{\setbox0=\hbox{$\exists$}%
             \hbox{\kern 0.125\wd0%
                   \vbox to \ht0{%
                      \hrule width 0.75\wd0%
                      \vfill%
                      \hrule width 0.75\wd0}%
                   \vrule height \ht0%
                   \kern 0.125\wd0}%
           }%
}
\begin{document}
$\letus$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest symbol in Unicode is ⊐ (U+2290), the Square Original Of.  Since this is a relational operator, you would want to change its spacing to

```
\newcommand\letsymbol{\mathord{\sqsupset}}
```

This works with numerous packages, including `unicode-math`, `amssymb` and `latexsym`.